# Non repeatable tablix in rdlc Report c#

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, windows, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I need to display some summary details in the RDLC report and also i need that in the form of table. I tried vertical tablix and bond values with DataSet but right now my problem is the summary details are showing vertically twice.

Eg.
I need

Sum1  val1

Sum2  val2

Sum3  val3

Total val1+val2+val3

BUT right now its displaying like

Sum1  val1

Sum2  val2

Sum3  val3

Total val1+val2+val3

Sum1  val1

Sum2  val2

Sum3  val3

Total val1+val2+val3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem ,i was taking the summary details from a Dataset that might return more than one row which is also using in the same report.Instead of that Wrote one more stored procedure for getting the Summary details alone as single row.Added One More DataSet for the Summary Details and Bound the Summary Details Tablix using that dataset